# Who is this Hindu spritual leader, who speaks on Krishna( mostly)

Tags: krishna, philosophy

I have received some forwarded messages( the sender does not know the name) and he talks very good on Hinduism Krishna and philosophy.

I will appreciate if this community help me identify the name of this gentlemen. He is from India. The full video is at [you tube](https://youtu.be/TyIDi7blNiE).

[image: Person whose name I need to find]

[image: BiggerPicture from video screenshot1]

[image]

Comment: I tried https://images.google.com/ for no result

Comment: Hi. Welcome to HSE.!! Please visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se), to get familiar with our site. Further, kindly have a look at: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Have an enriching Journey ahead.

Comment: PLease send the full video somewhere and link it here, also this question is little off topic.

Comment: @talk-is-cheap-show-me-code Video is posted at https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNpy8XqqaOCbX5EmtYXlF5XQO0LqLTxFp8Xr8twaZjmTO36HK7ehN5Cd1POVUD6ZQ?key=Wk5oUENBUnZzcFh4dF9XZzRZNTA1eDZKc05HWXNB

Comment: video is also posted at https://youtu.be/TyIDi7blNiE

Comment: I found him as  Shantilal Gulecha https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1hDKivt3B0